# Using Data Table Define Column From Character Vector

Tags: r, data.table

I've been getting used to data.tables and just cannot seem to find the answer to something that feels so simple (or at least is with data frames).

I want to use data.table to aggregate, however, I don't always know which column to aggregate ahead of time (it takes input from the user). I want to define what column to use based off of a character vector. Here's a short example of what I want to do:

```
require(data.table)

myDT <- data.table(a = 1:10, b = 11:20, n1 = c("first", "second"))
aggWith <- "a"
```

Now I want to use the aggWith object to define what column to sum on. This does not work:

```
> myDT.Agg <- myDT[, .(Agg = sum(aggWith)), by = .(n1)]
Error in sum(aggWith) : invalid 'type' (character) of argument
```

Nor does this:

```
> myDT.Agg <- myDT[, .(Agg = sum(aggWith)), by = .(n1), with = FALSE]
Error in sum(aggWith) : invalid 'type' (character) of argument
```

This does:

```
myDT.Agg <- myDT[, .(Agg = sum(a)), by = .(n1)]
```

However, I want to be able to define which column "a" is arbitrarily based off a character vector. I've looking through ?data.table, but am just not seeing what I need. Sorry in advance if this is really simple and I'm just overlooking something.

Comment: use `sum(get(aggWith))`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We could specify the 'aggWith' as `.SDcols` and then get the `sum` of `.SD`

```
 myDT[, list(Agg= sum(.SD[[1L]] )), by = n1, .SDcols=aggWith]
```

If there are multiple columns, then loop with `lapply`

```
 myDT[, lapply(.SD, sum), by = n1, .SDcols= aggWith]
```

---

Another option would be to use `eval(as.name`

```
 myDT[, list(Agg= sum(eval(as.name(aggWith)))), by = n1]
```

Comment: Also `get`, though maybe there's some reason to prefer the eval way over that?

Comment: @Frank I used to work with `eval`, though I am not sure whether this has any difference in efficiency with `get`.

Comment: if any of them would be faster I would expect it would be `eval(as.name(`

Comment: This is great stuff. Thank you!